# C++ How to use STL set container sort the name

Tags: c++

How to use STL set container sort the name?
such as I have 3 names, cat, apple, banana. after use set container, it will print out apple banana cat.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you use a `std::set` it will be sorted automatically.

Comment: That depends on comparison function you provide with contained data type: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/
The `Compare` template argument will let you change comparison function to the one you want.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::set` is always sorted when using the default comparator, so you can just iterate over it, and print the entries in this order.

```
 for(std::set<std::string>::const_iterator it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
      std::cout << "Entry:" << *it << std::endl;
```

or

```
 for(std::string const &s : myset)
      std::cout << "Entry:" << s << std::endl;
```

Only when you provide your own comparator, you can modify the sort order to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

STL containers such as map and set uses a Comparator function (by default `std::less<T>` where T is type of data which we put into set) to sort elements of container and also to check if some element already exists in container so that insertion of duplicate elements can be prevented.

In your case, set will be automatically sorted because default comparator `std::less<std::string>` will sort strings lexicographically.